# VBA - Send formulas down to last row of data based on data on another tab

Tags: excel, vba, automation, formula, autofill

I am trying to figure out a way to send formulas down to the last row of data based on the number of cells on a second tab that have data to capture all values excluding headers.

My formulas are on Sheet1 from cells A4:V4. Rows 1:3 on Sheet1 have headers. The number of cells I am trying to reference are on Sheet2. There are 88 cells with data on Sheet2 including headers on row 1, so 87 unique values. The way I am currently doing it just sends my formulas on Sheet1 down to row 88. I do not want the count to include headers on Sheet2 row 1.

It appears since there are 88 values on Sheet2 that is the total number of rows I am getting on Sheet1 including my 3 rows of headers, so 85 unique values. In total I should see 90 rows total (including existing headers) on Sheet1 but can't figure out how to do that. This is my formula:

```
Sub AmendRows()

Dim LastRow As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Locktabs False

worksheet1.Select
LastRow = worksheet1.Range("A5").EntireRow.Select
rows(ActiveCell.row & ":" & rows.count).ClearContents
rows(ActiveCell.row & ":" & rows.count).ClearFormats

worksheet1.Range("A4:V4").AutoFill Destination:=worksheet1("A4:V" & worksheet2.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlUp).row)

Locktabs True

worksheetmain.Select
MsgBox "Rows Amended!"


End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have spill range? Can you use the `Unique` function? If so, you could probably do what you're trying to accomplish without VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have not used the unique function for this task. I am unsure how it would apply in this situation. As a last resort I could always just drag the formulas down from A4:V4 down to A1000:V1000 and drag them down as more data is on Sheet2 but was hoping to have VBA just send down the formulas to make it cleaner based on how large the data set is on Sheet2.

Comment: You don´t need VBA for this, just use spill ranges. Is your data on a data table, or just a bunch of rows?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't used spill ranges. I am doing research on those now. My data is a bunch of rows currently.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub AmendRows()

    Dim worksheet1 As Worksheet, worksheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, rng As Range
    
    Set worksheet1 = Sheet1 ' as appropriate
    Set worksheet2 = Sheet2 ' as appropriate
    
    n = worksheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1 ' no header
    If n < 1 Then Exit Sub
   
    With worksheet1

        With .Rows("5:" & .Rows.Count)
            .ClearContents
            .ClearFormats
        End With
        
        Set rng = .Range("A4:V4")
        rng.AutoFill Destination:=rng.Resize(n)
        
    End With
    MsgBox n & " Rows Amended! " & rng.Resize(n).Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Formulas Down

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AmendRows()

    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As String = "A4:V4"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' ?
    
    Locktabs False
    
    Dim srCount As Long

    With worksheet2.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row _
            + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not slCell Is Nothing Then srCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
    End With
    
    With worksheet1.Range(DST_FIRST_ROW)
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row)
            .ClearContents
            .ClearFormats
        End With
        If srCount > 0 Then .Copy .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Locktabs True
    
    If Not worksheetmain Is ActiveSheet Then
        With worksheetmain
            If Not .Parent Is ActiveWorkbook Then .Parent.Activate
            .Select
        End With
    End If

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' ?
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Rows Amended!", vbInformation

End Sub
```